# Android Bluetooth App Pass Data to HTML5 Applicaiton

Tags: android, html, bluetooth

I have a simple Android native java application that reads data from a Bluetooth RFID enabled reader.

I would like to:

1. Start the bluetooth application from an HTML5 application
2. When data is read from the bluetooth app send it to the HTML5 application

Comment: Could you be more precise with "HTML5" application? Are you opening it with web browser or using tool like PhoneGap?

Comment: I'm not using any 3rd party tools.  The native application I have connects to the device using Bluetooth communicate via a bluetooth serial connection.  It simply reads the data and puts it into a list on the screen.  The issue I have is HTML5 does not have BT support.  So I need to be able to start this app from the browser and send data as it is read back to the browser.

I was thinking of embedding the browser in the application and passing data via the intent.  Though, I really wanted to do this without having install anything other than a simple "tag reader" and do the rest in HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely your device will require the use of the bluetooth SSP (serial port profile).

I'm confident you will not be able to access this from the android browser.

I see 2 options:

(1) Detach the requirement for your application to communicate with your RFID reader locally. Have your RFID data read transponders and send these events to the cloud directly via WIFI, Cellular Data, etc. Fetch this data from your HTML5 application. This has the penalties of high latency, and (relatively) high data throughput. This has the advantages of completely removes platform dependence from your application and allowing your tags to simply be pointers to data hosted somewhere centrally accessible.

(2) Use your own suggestion - write an android app that communicates with your device and embed a browser inside that app to host your HTML5 UI. I think this approach is more desirable. One thing that might make this slightly less painful is if you can find a way to manipulate a local, [HTML5 browser-based database](http://www.webkit.org/blog/126/webkit-does-html5-client-side-database-storage/), from your android app. To reiterate, I do not know if this is possible but if it is you simply use this local in-browser database as a way to exchange information and sync between your server, your local application, and your UI.